# Umbraco - http 500 Server Errors for .css and .js files

Tags: umbraco

What happened to our Umbraco instance?  It looks like this when I'm logged in, and when I check the browser console I see lots of 500 Internal Server Errors for both the backoffice and the front-end website, with failures for .css and .js files.

[image]

I've tried recycling, stopping and starting the app pool, and restarting IIS.  I've tried updating the clientDependency version number in clientDependency.config, that didn't work.

Comment: What is the error stack trace? If you don't know, check the server's event log viewer. If you don't have access to this, install Elmah into your site and have it record the errors. If you are using Umbraco v6+, check the logs in the ~/app_data/logs/ folder.

Answer (score 2):

I double-checked and I'd added a mime-type via the web.config (in the  section), and I'd also added it as a mime type via IIS.  This breaks loading of static content, so I defined the mime-type in the web.config only and removed it from IIS, and this fixed the issue.

Comment: If you add a remove before you add then you shouldn't run into issue like that in future e.g. 

  <remove fileExtension=".air" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />

Answer (score 2):

I tries to load a gif-file and just like ProNotion says:

I found this line in web.config without any remove element:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
```

Add change to

```
<remove fileExtension=".woff" />  
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a permissions problem. I'd suggest that you first need to try and find some detail on the 500 error. Can you inspect it for further detail?

If that doesn't help disable the ClientDependency framework by setting debug="true" on the compilation node of youur web.config file. It's located under the system.web node and looks like this:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

If you still have issues after that you can at least browse directly to those resources to view details of the error.

Simon